# Error : Phpize failed, some packages could not be installed

Tags: 16.04, server, php7

I am trying to install phpize on my ubuntu but everytime am getting this error.

I tried this command

```
apt install php7.0-dev
```

and used the sudo also:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-dev
```

but it doesn't work anymore.

after running the above commands, getting this error. Please help me out.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-dev : Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.7) but 7.0.33-8+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
              Recommends: dh-php but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@rohit-System-Product-Name:/home/rohit# sudo apt install php7.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-dev : Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.7) but 7.0.33-8+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
              Recommends: dh-php but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL & thus off-topic, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is off-topic also being supported only via Canonical through Ubuntu Advantage. Only questions specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu are on-topic for EOL or ESM releases. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Check your sources - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php7.0-common shows php7.0-common wanted is correct, but your sources are trying to provide something else (ie. you've added unofficial sources that have a release version that prevents official package - ie. check that source can be trusted; is packaged by correctly as it's higher version shows inexperience by packager or a specific reason).  https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/php7.0-dev is available, thus check your sources as valid (valid mirror that is maintained etc)